# Angular $http calling success on 404

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, promise, angular-promise

I'm exposing this function through a service:

```
function getData(url) {
    return $http.get(url).then(function (response) {
        return response.data;
    });
}
```

If the call succeeds, all is good - I get back a promise that resolves as expected.

If I pass in a URL that generates a 404, I get:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

on the line: `return response.data;`

I can see in Chrome's Developer Tools that the `GET` returns 404.

Why is Angular (v1.4.7, **also tried with v1.5.0**) calling my successCallback with `undefined` on an error?

(What I want to do is handle failures in the calling code.)

**Edit:** @jcaron pointed me in the right direction. The issue appears to be this configuration line (written by another developer):

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('ErrorInterceptor');
```

The interceptor must have a design flaw:

```
function ErrorInterceptor($q, $window) {
    return {
        response: function (response) {
            return response;
        },
        responseError: function (response) {
            if (response.status === 500) {
                $window.location.href = '/error';
                return $q.reject(response);
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Triggers the error callback here: https://jsfiddle.net/uz2dn4dh/ Perhaps something's different in your code? (assuming not much has changed from 1.4.7 to v1.4.8 in the fiddle)

Comment: Can you please test with http://httpstat.us/404 to make sure it is not something specific to your code...

Comment: Tried with httpstat; same issue.

Comment: I literally copied and pasted my code into a fork of @OmriAharon 's fiddle; it works properly there, but works incorrectly in my environment!

Comment: I only see one callback function, don't you need a second one to be the error callback?

Comment: @ItaloAyres I want the error callback to be in the calling function. `getData` returns a promise; I only want it to massage the output on success.

Comment: Do you have an interceptor somewhere that may be doing something weird?

Comment: I see, ok! Since you didn't share the controller code, I assumed you were handling all into the service to simplify the example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The interceptor must have a design flaw

Indeed it has. It returns `undefined` in the case of a rejection that is not a 500 status, which fulfills the promise. It should be

```
…
responseError: function (err) {
    if (err.status === 500) {
        $window.location.href = '/error';
    }
    return $q.reject(err); // always pass on rejection
}
```